# Http client always returns 404 if I do not use a http://localhost

Tags: c#, iis, web, asp.net-web-api, iis-8

Have a web api that works no problem if I call it from a browser.

I wanted to use HttpClient to call it:

```
 private const string BaseAddress = "http://13.195.151.169:80/VI_ProfilerWebServer/";

    private static readonly HttpClient HttpClient = new HttpClient();



    public static string PostAsJsonAsync(string route, Object jsonConverterParam)
    {

        string result = String.Empty;
        string jsonSerializable = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonConverterParam, Formatting.Indented);
        JObject postContent = JObject.Parse(jsonSerializable);

        try
        {
            var fullRoute = PrepareHttpRequest(route);
            using (HttpResponseMessage response = HttpClient.PostAsJsonAsync(fullRoute, postContent).Result)
            {
                result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                DumpUtils.DumpDataToFile(route, fullRoute, postContent, result, response);
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new HttpRequestException(result, ex);
        }

        return result;
    }
    private static string PrepareHttpRequest(string route)
    {

        HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue.Parse("application/json"));
        string requestUri = BaseAddress + route;
        return requestUri;
    }
```

This code works fine in the dev environment where the baseurl is a http://localhost address.  However, as soon as I change the baseUrl to say http://13.195.151.169:80/VI_ProfilerWebServer/ I get a 404.  If I use a browser and enter say http://13.195.151.169:80/VI_ProfilerWebServer/ (the URI the code constructs) the API call works as expected.

Comment: What is this IP, is it your public address? Some hints would be to check if the server is listening inside this ip range. And if it's your public IP, make sure you have port forwarding successfully set up on your router, although that's a topic outside of stack overflow's scope.

Answer (score 1):

IIS Express sets default binding to localhost only. However, you can change this by manually editing config file.

1. Right click on IIS Express Tray
2. Open running applications
3. Click on running application and at bottom it will display config file located at c:\Users\USERNAME\Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationHost.config
4. Add one more binding as shown below...

   <bindings>
         <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:5000:localhost" />

         <!-- Add following line -->

         <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:5000:*" />
     </bindings>

Comment: i found the applicationHost.config   changed it to ,<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:80:" />, and 404 again,
@Akash Kava